# Can not open linq-to-sql designer

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I was able to use linq-to-sql, now suddenly it stopped working. When double clicking dbml file, it says:

> "there is not editor for "...my.dbml" , make sure the application for
>   the file type(.dbml) is installed.

I tried to devenv /resetsettings, it does not help. So I repair/reinstall option for vs.net 2008 setup, it failed again without useful debugging logging?

Anyone has the same experience?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem like this: 
 I renamed my folder in `C:\Documents and Settings` and login again, let the system regenerate every thing for me, that solvde the problem, later I move my files from the renamed folder to the new user profile.

I guess this has something to do with me installation of F#, and IRON Ruby.